# Flash player won't send Referer Header when GET file

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, http-referer

I have this swf file, it will request for a `crossdomain.xml` file before playing. And the file host is configured to forbid "Hotlinking" (It means the server will check Referer Header, and return `302` if referer is not in the list).

Everything works well in chrome, but the request for `crossdomain.xml` file won't send `Referer` Header in IE, and thus cannot get the file.

I have tested IE 11, IE 8, and IE 9, 10 in IE 11's debug tool.

I am not the author of this swf file, and don't know how it works. Is there any solution? Thanks!

update:
I get no answer, so I have to reconfigure the server to disable 302 rewrite.

Comment: So what can you do? Do you have SWF sources?

Comment: @Tomek Sorry, I don't have the source code. I was wondering why IE do not send the Header. Is there any options to enable IE to send it?

Answer (score 0):

According to IE documentation :

> When linking from one document to another in Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, the Referer header will not be sent when the link is from an HTTPS page to a non-HTTPS page. The Referer header also will not be sent when the link is from a non-HTTP(S) protocol, such as file://, to another page.

you can read more info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178066/)

you can try to mimic something like that to override that behavior :

```
    //use browser sniffing to determine if IE or Opera (ugly, but required)
    var isOpera, isIE = false;
    if(typeof(window.opera) != 'undefined'){isOpera = true;}
    if(!isOpera && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Internet Explorer')){isIE = true;}

    //define for all browsers
    function goto(url){
      location.href = url;
    }

    //re-define for IE
    if(isIE){
      function goto(url){
        var referLink = document.createElement('a');
        referLink.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(referLink);
        referLink.click();
      }
    }
```

more info [here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html)

Comment: that should be only from https:// to http:// (what sort of makes sense) however when flash comes into play, it seems it does not send Referer no matter what protocol is being used when reqesting crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Flash will not send the referer header when requesting crossdomain.xml.

There is no workaround.